# How to prevent the onClick function to be fired when clicking on a nested span

Tags: html, angular

I am trying to disable a custom button component, but the (click) function triggers when a user clicks on the span element.

My use case is that if the custom button component is disabled, the onClick function should not be called.

**custom-button.component.ts**

```html
<div [ngClass]="isDisabled ? ('input-group disabled ') : ('input-group cursor-hand')" *ngIf="!hidden" >
  <span class="input-group-addon btn-addon btn-icon {{iconBgClass}}"*ngIf="iconClass ? true : false" [ngClass]="isDisabled ? ('input-group disabled ') : ('input-group cursor-hand')">
    <span [ngClass]="iconClass" *ngIf="iconClass ? true : false" ></span> <!-- iconet  -->
  </span>
  <button class="cursor-hand btn btn-primary {{customBtnColor}}" [disabled]="isDisabled" *ngIf="labelText?true:false" >
    {{ labelText }}
  </button>
</div>
```

The button is used in the following manner:

**potato.component.ts**

```html
<custom-button click=doStuff()" [iconClass]="'icon-done'" 
[isDisabled]="!changeMade" [labelText]="Fry potato">
</custom-button>
```

If changeMade is false, the button component is wholly grayed out. At the moment, clicking the span portion of the button still triggers the function.

[image: If a user clicks on the X, the function should not be called]

Comment: Can you post a minimal reproduceable example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is simple , by changing the css cursor style of your span element you will disable the event that is being fired, you can do it inline or create a new class in the css file like so :

```
.disableSpan {
   pointer-events:none;
}
```

and then on the html

```
<div [ngClass]="isDisabled ? ('input-group disabled ') : ('input-group cursor-hand')" *ngIf="!hidden" >
  <span  class="disableSpan input-group-addon btn-addon btn-icon {{iconBgClass}}"*ngIf="iconClass ? true : false" [ngClass]="isDisabled ? ('input-group disabled ') : ('input-group cursor-hand')">
    <span [ngClass]="iconClass" *ngIf="iconClass ? true : false" ></span> <!-- iconet  -->
  </span>
  <button class="cursor-hand btn btn-primary {{customBtnColor}}" [disabled]="isDisabled" *ngIf="labelText?true:false" >
    {{ labelText }}
  </button>
</div>
```

Edit:

I think i have missed the point where you only apply this effect when your variable 'isDisabled' is set to true, if so you can use the `[class.'cssClass']` tag that will apply to your html element if the set variable is set to true, in your case :

```
<div [ngClass]="isDisabled ? ('input-group disabled ') : ('input-group cursor-hand')" *ngIf="!hidden" >
  <span [class.disableSpan]="isDisabled" class="input-group-addon btn-addon btn-icon {{iconBgClass}}"*ngIf="iconClass ? true : false" [ngClass]="isDisabled ? ('input-group disabled ') : ('input-group cursor-hand')">
    <span [ngClass]="iconClass" *ngIf="iconClass ? true : false" ></span> <!-- iconet  -->
  </span>
  <button class="cursor-hand btn btn-primary {{customBtnColor}}" [disabled]="isDisabled" *ngIf="labelText?true:false" >
    {{ labelText }}
  </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Using class.disableSpan did not have an effect. But I moved disableSpan into the ngClass. I added a test (red background) to see if the class is applied, and it is. However, events are not being blocked :!

Answer (score 0):

use this function:

```
<custom-button click="changeMade ? doStuff(): false" [iconClass]="'icon-done'" 
[isDisabled]="!changeMade" [labelText]="Fry potato">
</custom-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I'd do is use `@Output` and `EventEmitter` to use the click event of the button itself.

**custom-button.template.html**

```html
<div [ngClass]="isDisabled ? ('input-group disabled ') : ('input-group cursor-hand')" *ngIf="!hidden" >
  <span class="input-group-addon btn-addon btn-icon {{iconBgClass}}"*ngIf="iconClass ? true : false" [ngClass]="isDisabled ? ('input-group disabled ') : ('input-group cursor-hand')">
    <span [ngClass]="iconClass" *ngIf="iconClass ? true : false" ></span> <!-- iconet  -->
  </span>
  <button class="cursor-hand btn btn-primary {{customBtnColor}}" [disabled]="isDisabled" *ngIf="labelText?true:false" (click)="clickEvent.emit()">
    {{ labelText }}
  </button>
</div>
```

**custom-button.component.ts**

```js
@Output()
clickEvent = new EventEmitter<any>();
```

**potato.template.html**

```html
<custom-button (clickEvent)="doStuff();" [iconClass]="'icon-done'" 
[isDisabled]="!changeMade" [labelText]="Fry potato">
</custom-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in css (but sass is better)

```
custom-button:disabled button{
  pointer-events: none;
}
```